# Ajax Form Sometimes Works, Sometime works and refreshes, Sometimes refreshes and fails ... Bwah?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've got an ajax form that seems to be very varied in its response. Sometimes it works, sometimes it refreshes but the data is still stored and sometimes if fails all together, and I can't seem to figure out why.

The Form

```
<form  >
    <label>Name</label>
        <input id="textname" type="text"/><br/>
    <label>Message</label>
        <textarea id="textmsg"></textarea><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return textin();"/><br/><br/>
    <label id="textresult"></label>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
function textin() { 
var name = $("input#textname").first().attr("value");
var msg = $("textarea#textmsg").first().attr("value");
    if (msg==null || msg=="")
                {
                    alert("Message cannot be Blank");
                    return false;
                };          
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=BASEURL?>/le-include/textin.php',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST", 
    data: {name : name, msg : msg},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#textname').attr('value', '');   
        $('#textmsg').attr('value', '');
        $('#textresult').html(data);
        $('#textresult').animate({ backgroundColor: $.Color( "rgba(2,232,87,1)" ), color: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,1)" ) });
        $('#textresult').animate({ backgroundColor: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,0)" ), color: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,0)" ) });
    }
})
};
```

textin.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($msg);

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

databaseSelect("$database");
$sql = "SELECT `ip` FROM `spamip` WHERE ip='$ip' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_error()) { print mysql_error(); print '<br/>'; };
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num == 0) { 
        $date = date_create();  
        $stamp = date_format($date, 'U');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `texts` (`name`, `message`, `date`, `ip`) VALUES ('$name', '$msg', FROM_UNIXTIME('$stamp'), '$ip');";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_error()) { 
                echo "Error"; 
            } else { 
                echo "Success"; }
    } else {
        echo "Your IP has been marked as Spam";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML should be:**

```
<form onsubmit="return textin();">
    <label>Name</label>
        <input id="textname" type="text"/><br/>
    <label>Message</label>
        <textarea id="textmsg"></textarea><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/><br/><br/>
    <label id="textresult"></label>
</form>
```

because otherwise think about what will happen when you press enter while you have focus on text box with id textname

**jQuery should be:**

```
function textin() { 
var name = $("input#textname").first().attr("value");
var msg = $("textarea#textmsg").first().attr("value");
    if (msg==null || msg=="")
                {
                    alert("Message cannot be Blank");
                    return false;
                };          
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=BASEURL?>/le-include/textin.php',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST", 
    data: {name : name, msg : msg},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#textname').attr('value', '');   
        $('#textmsg').attr('value', '');
        $('#textresult').html(data);
        $('#textresult').animate({ backgroundColor: $.Color( "rgba(2,232,87,1)" ), color: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,1)" ) });
        $('#textresult').animate({ backgroundColor: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,0)" ), color: $.Color( "rgba(0,0,0,0)" ) });
    }
});
return false;
};
```

because otherwise the form will be posted normally and not with ajax.

**Additional information:**

`.attr("value")` can be replaced in the short command `.val()`

and

`.attr("value", "")` can be replaced in the short command `.val("")`

Impotent! I don't know if you don't want to but you don't check if there is a name given.

You can check with `error: function() {}` if the internet connection is down or something else happened and give the user an error message.

Check in PHP if the data is send (`isset($var)`) because otherwise maybe someone is playing around with your website and go to the page and get error messages and that wouldn't be nice.

Comment: thanks @micha
That    return false;    makes allot of sense, the form part i'm still confused over, but it works, so I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given above but let me just add the best way to do something like that is return false. When you return false you will stop the form from submitting (in case of an error).

So let's say I have a form, frmMain; we click a button, it has to do some validation and if successful retrieve some input from the server via AJAX and then post the form. In the jscript ajax function I will call AJAX server.php but also return FALSE to onsubmit (the form). This will stop the form from executing. When AJAX server.php sends back a reply, if it's the correct reply, then in jscript I put frm.submit, or in other words post the form after ajax has returned something. But note, when the form do posts, its done from jscript/after ajax has completed successfully.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: yes it was, still to sort of new to javascript and ajax. Thank you.

Comment: Try W3schools for their tutorials. If still getting trouble send me an e-mail : d_rattansingh@yahoo.com and I would send you one or 2 simple of my examples so you would get the idea.